# __call method in php

Tags: php, arrays, magic-methods

I wrote a custom call method in a class which is then extended by other classes to call methods in a unique way. the problem is - calling the classes own methods in side the class or external methods not in the array of existing methods triggers the exception.

I am looking to alter this call method to say: *Check the array of existing method, not found? see if the method in general exists - not found? throw the exception.*

**The method is defiend as such:**

```
public function __call($name, $param = null){
    foreach($this->_methods as $class_name=>$methods){
        foreach($methods as $method){
            if($name === $method){
                return call_user_func_array(array($this->_class_objects[$class_name], $method), $param);
            }
        }
    }

    throw new AisisCore_Loader_LoaderException("Method: " .$name. 
                        " does not exist or it's access is not public");
}
```

The method is pretty obvious in what it does. But its limited to whats in the `$this->_methods` array, which is good for "look here first" but not good when the method comes from another object not in that array.

Comment: [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php): It is recommended that you do not use function names with __ in PHP unless you want some documented magic functionality. You cannot throw an exception from within a __call() method. Doing so will result in a fatal error.

Comment: Thats where your wrong because I have managed to throw an exception and it's caught - and its processed. Either way I need this to check here and then any where else for the method being called. and the PHP Docs say nothing about **not** changing the behavior of magic methods.

Comment: Rather than an array of allowed methods, can you not simply check if an object supports your method with method_exists()?

Comment: No - I have a set of methods in an array and if the method being called is not there I should continue on with the call method.

Comment: "but not good when the method comes from another object" sooo call the method on the object that actually contains that method?